# Active Directory Support Folder Redirection AND Portable Home Directories?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, active-directory, mac-osx

Does anyone here know if Active Directory will support the use of both Windows Folder Redirection and Mac OS X's Portable Home Directories for synchronizing a user's files to a remote share?  I want to synchronize my user's files with a remote share as a way of backing up their data.  This is fairly straightforward if a user has only a Windows computer or only a Mac computer.  However, will Active Directory support a situation in which a user has both types of computers or they have a Mac on which they're running Windows within Parallels?  If I configure a remote share via Group Policies for their Windows files and then configure a different share for their Mac files via ADUC, when they change a file on either computer, will AD know which computer the file was changed on and synchronize that file with the appropriate remote folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory doesn't pick which files to sync. In both cases the logic is on the desktop computer side, using file timestamp data (and at least in the case of Windows some metadata) to determine which file is newer.

Some data on the Windows sync:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Understanding-offline-files#section_2